# Trying to write a regex that will match anything that begins with ```Volume[WD__dss```

Tags: regex, grafana

I am working with Grafana and I am trying to write a regex that will match anything that begins with `Volume[WD1__dss`so that I can use it in a series override.  I have tried to simply use `/^Volume[WD1__dss*/` but it does not seem to work.  Sorry, still very new to writing regex.

Comment: You need to escape the `[` and `*` should be `.*`.

Comment: You don't even need `.*` at the end, since the regexp will just match the beginning.

Comment: So easy!  Thank you!